# Depth of $\operatorname{SHA-256}$ implementation by fan-in $2$ and fan-out $1$ Boolean circuits?

Tags: sha-256, implementation, complexity, computational-complexity-theory, circuit

A fan-in $2$ and fan-out $1$ Boolean circuit is a circuit consisting of $\operatorname{AND}$, $\operatorname{OR}$ and $\operatorname{NOT}$ gates where number of inputs to $\operatorname{AND}$ and $\operatorname{NOT}$ are constrained to be $2$ and number of output gates any of the gates can be connected to is $1$.

> I am wondering if $\operatorname{SHA-256}$ is implemented as a multi-output (all hash bits computed by one circuit) fan-in $2$ Boolean circuit what would its depth be?

> Can its depth be in the low $10$s while the number of gates could be in say range $10^6$ to $10^9$?

Direct sequential implementation of rounds would warrant a depth of at least $64$ since $\operatorname{SHA-256}$ employs $64$ rounds.

It has to be a clever optimized design.

Comment: Many definitions of fan-in 2 count NAND and NOR gates as depth 1. I even was taught to count AND and OR as depth 2 (on the grounds that AND is often physically implemented as NAND followed by NOT), and having a discussion this was unwaranted given modern technology where the cost of routing signals dominates logic. I don't know how to make a definitive answer to the question as in the title, but I'm ready to bet the house that for depth of 10 (or even 32), the answer is _way_ above $10^{10}$.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are going to implement it homomorphically. Here is an article about it: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-45239-0_3

Comment: @fgrieu Can you quantify way above $10^{10}$? We can pick one definition of fan-in $2$ and fan-out $1$.

Comment: @kelalaka Is the terminology levels similar to depth?

Comment: Sorry my best justification is qualitative: cost at fixed depth is likely exponential (or worse) with the number of  rounds, and 64 is a lot. Also consider the reference pointed by kelalaka uses hundreds of gates for a single round with depth >40.

Comment: In FHE, the depth usually represents the multiplication level.

Comment: By the [usual definition of "fan out"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan-out), that means an output can drive a single input. That just can't apply to what drives the inputs of the overall circuit (one can't even make a XOR with such constraints). And applied to the output of internal gates, it makes the task even more impossible. But I still don't see an easy quantitative proof.

Comment: @fgrieu I believe you cannot get a proof but heuristics based on current knowhow XOR(a,b)=ab'+a'b=OR(AND(a,NOT(b)),AND(NOT(a),b)). I see a depth 2 fan-in 2 and fan-out 1 Boolean circuit having negated inputs.

Comment: @1.. Agreed, including your count (my mistake). Heuristics is all I see possible.

Comment: @1..: note that while you could implement XOR with a fan-out of 1, you can't actually use it (because whatever is providing the inputs to the XOR would require a fanout of 2).  Of course, unless you are talking about Quantum Computation (where you don't think in terms of AND and OR, but instead things like CNOT), I don't know how fanout is relevant; certainly FHE has no limit on fanout...

Comment: Do not understand $XOR$ is in $NC^0$ ${\bf{formula}}$ is a standard result. Formulas unlike circuits are constructed of gates which are fan-out $1$. These are standard established results. I am asking direct Boolean circuit implementation. No quantum or FHE is referred except by commenters. Since fan-out is $1$ the number of gates is bound above by $256$ times the number of gates required by the highest complexity hashbit. $256$ comes because there are $256$ binary outputs in $SHA256$.